# Model of Persistent Classes

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I'am very new to `hibernate` and `ORM` and I have question:

I have three poco/pojo classes and generated tables from that classes.

```
OrdersClass
{
 OrderNumber
 Date
 Sum
 *Products
 *Employee
}

ProductClass
{
 ProductName
 Price
}

EmployeeClass
{
 FirstName
 LastName
}
```

I want to display mix of these tables into grid. So grid columns will be:
`OrdersClass.OrderNumber`, `Emplyee.FirstName`.

So my question is:

Should I make new entity that will model view of grid:

```
EntityForGrid
{
  OrderNumber
  FirstName
}
```

or should I base on poco classes and load data i.e

```
var orders = session.CreateQuery("from Orders WHERE something").List<Orders>();
var employee = session.CreateQuery("from Employee WHERE something").List<Employee>();
```

so all data are mapped like database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you have done your mappings, but if it is done correctly you should have a a getter in your Orders class named "getEmployee"

Sou you could query for all orders that meet your WHERE and than for each entry call the "getEmployee" to obtain the corisponding employee. In this way you get a relation... what is quite tricky to get with your two selects.

Or if you like you could due something like this (in Java)

```
final String query= "select o.num, e.first from Order o join o.employee where something";
List<Object[]> result= (List<Object[]>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query).list();
```

(I imagine you're on C# or something, so you need to convert it to that.)

Now you have a list of Objects that contain two string values each, and those are going to be your results.

Basically if you're using ORM like this it is similar to a direct DB connection. It's power comes when u're able to use my first proposal

Comment: I use code first metod, so i don't know if i should have getter getEmployee

Comment: Call it as you like, but if you have a realtion between your tables you should model it somehow. E.g. your order table will have a relation in some form to employee --> follow that relation and you'll get your join

Answer (score 0):

Your Order class is aggregate. So you can bind ICollection to your grid. First column would be bind to Order.OrderNumber, second to Order.Employee.FirstName. Employers u can fetch in one query with quering orders, or u can use lazy loading Employers collection. It depends on your fetch strategy.